# Can't include NDK header files

Tags: android, android-ndk, include, ndk-build

i wrote a simple **C++** Programm using NDK, and it works fine.
   Now I want to add the following header file for using logging functions:

```
android\log.h
```

My **Android.mk** look like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkmodulea
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkmodulea.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My .cpp file starts like this:

```
#include <jni.h>            
#include <string.h>
#include <android\log.h>
```

if i try to run **ndk-build** (via terminal) inside the android project folder, 
I'll get following error message:

```
Compile++ thumb  : ndkmodulea <= ndkmodulea.cpp
jni/ndkmodulea.cpp:4:25: fatal error: android\log.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/ndkmodulea/ndkmodulea.o] Error 1
```

Can somebody help or teach me how to correctly include such header files?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use forward slashes in `#include` paths:

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!!! :) I almost got crazy editing the Android.mk file!

- Windows user have to use backslashes

    #include <android\log.h>

- Linux user have to use slashes

    #include <android/log.h>

Comment: Forward slashes *should* work on all platforms - and its safer just to use them if you can.

Comment: just to confirm they work on every platform i've ever touched - pretty much every ppc, arm, x86/x64 and mips that has been in a phone, pc or game console - and using most compilers you would care about gcc, snc, dmc, ghc, cl (msvc), clang, intel and code warrior...